# Generate postgresql database backup using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm newbie to python and sql.

1. I want to list all tables in database using python script
2. I want to get create sql query for existing postgresql table using python

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your needs are not very clear, give more information about your environment. And why use python you don't really need it. You can use pg_dump tool and set timer or evenement with bash script ?

```
pg_dump dbname > dbname.bak
```

You can recover your old database .bak :

```
psql dbname < dbname.bak
```

No sql required.

If you really need to do it with python and SQL queries, use psycopg2 library for establish connection and execute some SQL queries:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
def pgsql_connect():
# Try to connect to an existing postgresql database
db = getattr(g,'db_pgsql', None)
if db is None:
    try:
        g.db_pgsql = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=xxx user=xxxx password=xxxx")
        return g.db_pgsql
    except Exception as e :
        print('Error')

else:
    print('Already connected before')
    return db

db = pgsql_connect()
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(" //Your SQL query// select * from Table1;")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return rows
except Exception as e :
    print('unavailable')
```

Table1 in rows[].

(This is not a good solution for doing back up)

Comment: To add to this excellent answer - using queries like that to perform a database backup has the drawback of being slower, and not backing up the structure of the tables.

Comment: Yes, constraints, functions is not extractable in SQL, defenitely not a good solution ^^